# How to use Hibernate 'SELECT' query for JSON output to retrieve data form selected columns?

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I have a table: Address(String ID, street, streetName, state, postalCode)

I want to get the output as JSON data for only the state and postalCode columns. To do this, I tried to use Hibernate with the following query into my DAO layer:

```
Query query = s.createQuery("select a.state, a.postalCode from Address a");  
List list = query.list();
```

And I am getting output like:

```
{"JSON":"success","authority":null,"gridModel":[1,2,3]}
```

But my expected output is like the following:

```
{"JSON":"success","authority":null,"gridModel":[{"state":"NY","postalCode":"123"},{"state":"VA","postalCode":"222"},{"state":"MD","postalCode":"159"}]}
```

Code for that table:

```
@Entity  
public class Address implements Serializable {        
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(...)  
    @SequenceGenerator(...)  
    @Column(name = "ID")  
    String ID;  
    String street;  
    String streetName;  
    String state;  
    String postalCode;  

    // getters and setters  
}
```

struts.xml file code:

```
<action name="jsonFormatDate" class="com.example.ActionClass" method="jsonFormatDate">
        <result type="json" />
</action>
```

Can anybody tell me what I have to add / modify the code to get the above output? Do I need to do some extra mapping or modify the query etc. for getting that desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you generating the JSON?

Comment: Which library you are using to convert Bean to JSON ?

Comment: @ CodeChimp: I am using Struts 2. I am able to generate JSON for the query "from Address a" which gives me all columns JSON format data. But I want to generate JSON data for only the mentioned 2 columns.

Comment: @ Jaffar Ramay: I am using struts2-json-plugin